# Can the Green Lantern make kryptonite?

Tags: dc, superman, green-lantern, kryptonite

Kryptonite is green....   Can the Green Lantern defend himself against Kryptonians?   Or can the ring not make something that acts sufficiently like kryptonite?

Comment: @Thaddeus - I agree. Dupe.

Comment: @Richard and others:   Not disagreeing that the question is answered there, but searching "green lantern kryptonite" does not reveal that answer.   And someone seeking the question I asked will not look for "Who can stop Superman?".   So does this really count as a duplicate?   Seems more like the answer should be given and a link presented for the realted question.

Comment: OK -- I read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled   which is pretty clear that duplicate are not a bad thing and should persist unless they are literally identical.   But this seems a little at odds with the banner text itself: "If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question"....  my key point being that while the answers to the duplicate cover the question, the duplicate ***question*** doesn't cover this question.

Comment: The mark of a dupe is if the answer to a similar question answers your question. If you're unsatisfied, you can take it to meta or chat, edit it in such a way to make it less dupey or post a bounty on the dupe question asking for more info.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** This has actually happened on a number of occasions;

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Green Lantern rings are capable of creating Kryptonite and Kryptonite Radiation because the rings are capable of Energy Projection and can therefore mimic certain types of materials and energy signatures.

[From Wikia](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Ring):

> Energy Projection: The ring can be used to fire blasts of Oan energy
>   or create weapons such as projectiles of them. The ring can project
>   beams of force powered by the will of the user. The ring can be used
>   to produce kryptonite and kryptonite radiation.
>
> DC Comics Presents Vol 1 26